# Check if a number is an integer or not in C language

Tags: c, visual-c++

I want to check if a number given by a user is an integer or not in another way i want to verify if the input data is between `−(2)^31= −2,147,483,648`  and `((2)^31) - 1 =2,147,483,647`
this is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int x;

    int y = pow(3,31) * (-1);
    int z = pow(3,32) - 1;
    printf("\n\ty = %d et z = %d \n\n", y, z);
    scanf("%d", &x);
    if ((x < y) || (x > z)) {
        printf("x is not an integer");
    }
    else {
        printf("x is an integer");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But while running the program the result always showing me `x is integer` even if x is greater than 2,147,483,647 or lesser than −2,147,483,648.

Comment: The value of a variable `x` of type `int` can't possibly fall outside the range representable in `int`, by definition.

Comment: I don't understand, you are asking about using the C language but you have a lot of C++ language tags.  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has `cin, cout,` inheritance and overloading of functions.  The C language doesn't.

Comment: BTW, the `pow` function in C++ returns a floating point value.  You may get inaccuracies do to conversion from floating point to integer.  Best to use an integer exponentiation function.

Comment: `strtol()`is a good starting point.

Comment: BTW, numbers can be valid and outside of your range checking.  You'll need a 64-bit or larger integer to hold your range.  The value `pow(3, 31)` is larger than `(pow(2, 32) - 1)`.

Comment: Am I right that you're trying to check if a value stored in  an `int` variable is outside the `int` type range...?

Comment: @CiaPan yeah you are right this is my problem i don't know how to check if a number is indeed an integer in c

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Re “You may get inaccuracies do to conversion from floating point to integer”: That is not where inaccuracies in using `pow` to calculate integer powers arise.

Comment: So you have two paths to choose: either write your own function to parse integers, which will scan and interpret a string of digits _without_ using a built-in conversion to the `int` or `unsigned int` type; or simply use a standard conversion by `scanf` and test if it succeeded. The latter requires testing a return value from `scanf` and possibly using the "%n" conversion specifier to obtain a number of input characters converted by "%d" or "%u".

Comment: Why do you need to check it? What's wrong with the built-in ways to input integers?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: There is no direct built-in way.

Comment: @CiaPan: `scanf` will not reliably report a failure if the input is out of range. Per C 2018 7.21.6.2 10, “… if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil `strtol` is a direct enough built-in way. In addition, mainstream implementations actually define this behaviour so one can reliably use `scanf` and friends.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you, I didn't remember that. So, if the input may be out of the expected range (which means almost always) we can't  rely on std lib and we should write our own parsers for everything instead.....

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: If `strtol` were a “direct” way (it is not; multiple additional steps are needed), then you should tell OP, not allude to some unstated “direct” way. What mainstream implementations define the behavior? Apple’s default libraries do not; scanning “999999999999999999” for `%d` yields a match that produces −1486618625.

Comment: @EricPostpischil try checking `errno`. That's how gcc, clang and msvc all work. What did you expect?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: I tested; `errno` remains zero. Please show documentation for your statement that mainstream implementations define the behavior.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: [OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/B1-dsk-xP) says it uses GCC (and, I expect, the GNU C Library), but it also accepts “999999999999999999” and does not set `errno`. The same for MSVC.

Comment: @EricPostpischil it is clearly documented in glibc documentation on the `scanf` man page, However there seems to be a bug in glibc, it only sets errno when the number in the input is too large to fit in `long long`. I had no idea, I checked `long long`. What's more funny, Microsoft is doing the same thing. It looks like they are stealing bugs from one another.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: Please provide a proper citation: a URL or bibliographic reference if not online, location within the document (clause/section/page number), and sample text.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Linux `man 3 scanf`, section ERRORS. FreeBSD and consequently Apple do not document it. I have no idea where to find Microsoft documentation, I can only check what their compiler does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing whether input is a valid `int` decimal numeral or is a decimal numeral in [-2<sup>31</sup>, 2<sup>31</sup>) is actually a bit complicated. The C standard does not provide a direct way to do this. What we can do is:

- Read characters and check to see whether they are in the expected form: spaces, an optional minus sign (hyphen), and digits. (Any non-digits after the digits will be allowed and ignored.)
- Try using `strtol` to convert the numeral to a `long`. We use `strtol` because there is no C-standard library routine for converting to an `int`  (or your fixed bounds using 2<sup>31</sup>) that provides error indications.
- Compare the `long` produced by `strtol` to the `int` bounds.

Example code for `int` bounds follows. If you want bounds of -2147483648 and 2147483647 instead, substitute those for `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`. To be completely safe, the code should actually use `long long` and `strtoll`, since the C standard does not require `long` to be able to represent −2147483648.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
    //  Prepare a buffer.
    size_t BufferSize = 100, BufferUsed = 0;
    char *Buffer = malloc(BufferSize * sizeof *Buffer);

    //  Skip white space.
    int c;
    do
        c = getchar();
    while (isspace(c));

    if (c == EOF)
    {
        printf("Input is not an int:  EOF before \"-\" or digit seen.\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    //  Accept a hyphen as a minus sign.
    if (c == '-')
    {
        Buffer[BufferUsed++] = c;
        c = getchar();
    }

    //  Accept digits.
    while (isdigit(c))
    {
        Buffer[BufferUsed++] = c;
        if (BufferSize <= BufferUsed)
        {
            BufferSize *= 2;
printf("Realloc:  size = %zu, used = %zu.\n", BufferSize, BufferUsed);
            char *NewBuffer = realloc(Buffer, BufferSize * sizeof *NewBuffer);
            if (!NewBuffer)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error, unable to allocate %zu bytes.\n",
                    BufferSize);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            Buffer = NewBuffer;
        }
        c = getchar();
    }

    //  Ensure we saw at least one digit (input is not blank or just a hyphen).
    if (BufferUsed == 0 || BufferUsed == 1 && Buffer[0] == '-')
    {
        printf("Input is not an int:  No digits present.\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    //  Put back the unaccepted character, if any.
    if (c != EOF)
        ungetc(c, stdin);

    //  Terminate the string.
    Buffer[BufferUsed] = 0;

    //  Attempt to convert the numeral to long.
    char *End;
    errno = 0;
    long x = strtol(Buffer, &End, 10);

    //  Test whether strtol succeeded.
    if (*End)
    {
        /*  I do not expect this to occur since we already tested the input
            characters.
        */
        printf("Input is not an int:  strtol rejected %c.\n", *End);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    if (errno == ERANGE)
    {
        printf("Input is not an int:  strtol reported out of range.\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    if (x < INT_MIN || INT_MAX < x)
    {
        printf("Input is not an int:  Value is outside bounds.\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    printf("Input is an int, %ld.\n", x);

    free(Buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i think i should store the number on a char array and check if it contains the float character `'.'`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
char number[10];
int flag=0,i = 0;
printf("\n\nEnter a number: ");
scanf("%s", number);
while(number[i++] != '\0'){
if(number[i] == '.'){
     flag = 1;
     break;}}
if(flag)
printf("\n\n\n\tyou Entered a Floating Number not an integer number\n\n");
else
printf("\n\n\n\t you Entered an integer Number\n\n");
return 0;}
```